# Can someone please explain to me why the knife tool is not working on some of the faces

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I have been stuck here for a while and I couldn't figure out why the knife tool is not working on some parts of the mesh.

This will clear a lot of confusion for me so please help me out here.
Here is a video showing the problem : https://youtu.be/bjkp75bwdos

Thank you!

Comment: can u pls provide blend file?

Comment: I actually removed that part and started over again, seems to be working as intended now but I am sure I will face this problem again.
I was thinking there is some obvious reason why the knife tool acted that way.

Comment: On  the video when you cut the top face two edges appears till the side of the disc. This means the middle face covers the whole area of the circle so the smaller faces on the side are overlapping with it. Probably Blender can't choose which face you clicked on. Take care to avoid overlapping faces.

Comment: @FFeller
I see! I will be more careful 
At least I understand this shouldn't happen. Thank you very much

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.